# socket.io emit returns the same value

Tags: javascript, sockets

Quick question here can someone tell me why everytime I emit from client `attack` the `enemyHealth` and `userHealth` always stays at 94 every emit and it's not decreasing by 6 on every attack emit ? It only decreases on first click.

```
socket.on('attack', () => {

    var userDamage = 6;

    var enemyDamage = 6;

    var userHealth = 100;
    var enemyHealth = 100;

    var userDmg = userDamage;
    var enemyDmg = enemyDamage;

    userHealth -= enemyDmg;
    enemyHealth -= userDmg;

    console.log(enemyHealth);

});
```

Comment: you are reassigning static values on each run of the 'attack' handler. The initial values should all be created outside your 'attack' handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `enemyHealth` and `userHealth` remain the same on each `attack` event is that those variables are being declared in the `attack` event itself, meaining their value will always be the same each time the `attack` event occurs.

One way to resolve your issue is to simply move the declaration and initialisation of `enemyHealth` and `userHealth` outside of your `attack` event handler like so:

```
// Declare these variables outside of the attach handler so that their updated 
// values are retained between attack events
var userHealth = 100;
var enemyHealth = 100;

socket.on('attack', () => {

    var userDamage = 6;    
    var enemyDamage = 6;

    // Remove the variable declarations from inside the attack event
    // var userHealth = 100;
    // var enemyHealth = 100;

    var userDmg = userDamage;
    var enemyDmg = enemyDamage;

    userHealth -= enemyDmg;
    enemyHealth -= userDmg;

    // Now this value goes down each time the attach event occours
    console.log(enemyHealth);

});
```